# Flyway Database Migrations on Bluehost Shared Hosting

Tags: database-migration, flyway, bluehost

Folks,

I'm trying to use Flyway on a shared Bluehost server and I'm getting a very cryptic error. Not sure how to troubleshoot.. I'm confident that the basic connection / credentials are working, since changing flyway config settings to a wrong password produces a different error.

Note that I'm able to connect to the database from the command line from the server box using 'mysql -u blah -p' just fine.

Any hints on how to troubleshoot the below? Output from `flyway -X init` is below.

Flyway config file: http://pastebin.com/8dsWE3W2

Output from ./flyway -X init

```
/usr/bin/tput
Flyway (Command-line Tool) v.3.0

DEBUG: Adding location to classpath: /home1/philost2/checkout/cocktailbuilder-master/server/_devtools/flyway/bin/../jars/mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar
DEBUG: Adding location to classpath: /home1/philost2/checkout/cocktailbuilder-master/server/_devtools/flyway/bin/../jars/h2-1.3.170.jar
ERROR: Unexpected error
org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource (jdbc:mysql://localhost/philost2_cocktailbuilder_prod?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false) for user '<redacted>'
   at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.DriverDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverDataSource.java:266)
   at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:226)
   at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:50)
   at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1144)
   at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.init(Flyway.java:970)
   at org.flywaydb.commandline.Main.executeOperation(Main.java:118)
   at org.flywaydb.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:88)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '??????????????' at line 1
   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1049)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4232)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4164)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2615)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2776)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2832)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.configureClientCharacterSet(ConnectionImpl.java:1937)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:3720)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2554)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2321)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:413)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:344)
   at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.DriverDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverDataSource.java:264)
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace and debug output (-X), the MySQL driver version, the MySQL DB version and your Flyway config file.

Comment: Added the info you requested. Please help - can't get this figured out :(

Comment: Still missing the MySQL driver version and the MySQL DB version